# I declare an image in XAML but want to set the image thats shown from C# as it is in the isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I can declare my image like so in my xaml

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanelx" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,190,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
</Grid>
```

I can load my image from isolated storage via the .xaml.cs like so

```
void loadImage()
{
    // The image will be read from isolated storage into the following byte array

    byte[] data;

    // Read the entire image in one go into a byte array

    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("0.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            data = new byte[isfs.Length];
            isfs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            isfs.Close();
        }
    }

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.SetSource(ms);

    Image image = new Image();
    image.Height = bi.PixelHeight;
    image.Width = bi.PixelWidth;

    image.Source = bi;    
}
```

When I Type MyImage. I cant find a method to set it to image which I just created. Can any of you guys advise please?

Answer (score 6):

```
void loadImage() { // The image will be read from isolated storage into the following byte array

        byte[] data;

        // Read the entire image in one go into a byte array

        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("0.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                data = new byte[isfs.Length];
                isfs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                isfs.Close();
            }
        }

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.SetSource(ms);

        MyImage.Source = bi;    
    }
}
```

You need to set `MyImage.Source = bi;` .
That was it

And a little refactoring:

```
void loadImage() { 
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("0.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bi.SetSource(isfs);
            }
        }

        MyImage.Source = bi;    
    }
}
```